# Flutter: A value of type 'GoogleSignInAccount?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'GoogleSignInAccount'

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin, google-authentication, dart-null-safety

I am trying to connect my flutter application with firebase google authentication.

[The error states "The property 'authentication' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jATru.png)

my added dependencies are:
firebase_auth: ^1.3.0
google_sign_in: ^5.0.4
firebase_core: ^1.2.1

and i have gradle 6.7

the error:
"The property 'authentication' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')."

Comment: add ? in    await _googleSignIn?.signIn();

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await gooleSignIn.signIn();
```

Add ? right after GoogleSignInAccount.